# Matlab - product-like simplification of trigonometric function

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, symbolic-math

Consider the following:

```
syms T fi t real
fun = symfun(sin(T+fi)+cos(T+fi),[T fi]);
fun = expand(fun);
```

which yields:

```
cos(T)*cos(fi) - sin(T)*sin(fi) + cos(T)*sin(fi) + sin(T)*cos(fi)
```

Now if I use either `simplify` or `combine` I get:

```
2^(1/2)*sin(pi/4 + T + fi)
```

Could you please tell me which function will let me obtain product form, i.e.:

```
cos(fi)*(cos(T)+sin(T)) + sin(fi)*(cos(T)-sin(T))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I may have found a way to do this using [`collect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/collect.html) – it works in R2016a:

```
syms T fi t real
fun = symfun(sin(T+fi)+cos(T+fi),[T fi]);
fun = expand(fun);

fun2 = collect(fun,[cos(fi) sin(fi)])
```

which returns `(cos(T) + sin(T))*cos(fi) + (cos(T) - sin(T))*sin(fi)`.

This usage of `collect` (collecting functions of a variable) isn't really documented. I tried this out after reading through the examples for [MuPAD's `collect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/collect.html) upon which `collect` is likely based on or related to.

Comment: Maybe calling `children` on that and separately simplifying, then simplifying the rejoined version will help;)

Answer (score 0):

In R2012b `simplify` gives me

```
cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)
```

so you probably have a newer version. Still: it's hard to come up with a specific simplification of a symbolic expression, especially if trigonometric functions are involved.

If you're specifically looking for an expression in terms of sines, you could try [`rewrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/choose-function-to-rearrange-expression.html):

```
>> rewrite(fun,'sin')

ans(T, fi) =

sin(T + fi) - 2*sin(T/2 + fi/2)^2 + 1
```

The above output is again from R2012b, it's highly likely that your newer version will do better.

---

I originally suggested that you try `simple`, which by default (with 0 output variables) will try a bunch of various simplification attempts, and tell you the result. However, as [@horchler pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978059/matlab-product-like-simplification-of-trigonometric-function/37978436?noredirect=1#comment63403240_37978436), this function has been deprecated and no longer available after 2015a. Anyway, here's the output from this now-gone function from R2012b, which might give you hints regarding more low-level functions to try:

```
>> syms T fi t real
>> fun = symfun(sin(T+fi)+cos(T+fi),[T fi]);
>> simple(fun)

simplify:

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


radsimp:

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


simplify(100):

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


combine(sincos):

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


combine(sinhcosh):

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


combine(ln):

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


factor:

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


expand:

cos(T)*cos(fi) - sin(T)*sin(fi) + cos(T)*sin(fi) + sin(T)*cos(fi)


combine:

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


rewrite(exp):

exp(- T*i - fi*i)*(1/2 + i/2) + exp(T*i + fi*i)*(1/2 - i/2)


rewrite(sincos):

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


rewrite(sinhcosh):

cosh(T*i + fi*i) - sinh(T*i + fi*i)*i


rewrite(tan):

(2*tan(T/2 + fi/2))/(tan(T/2 + fi/2)^2 + 1) - (tan(T/2 + fi/2)^2 - 1)/(tan(T/2 + fi/2)^2 + 1)


mwcos2sin:

sin(T + fi) - 2*sin(T/2 + fi/2)^2 + 1


collect(T):

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)


ans(T, fi) =

cos(T + fi) + sin(T + fi)
```

where the final line is the shortest representation found from the previous list, that would be your single return value. You can take your pick from the list. Your version will probably produce a more diverse set of outputs.

Comment: @Maverick well...does it help?:) Does your version find this expression?

Comment: `simple` has been deprecated and removed. I believe the last version that it was available for was R2015a.

Comment: @horchler aaah, thanks for the tip, that's why I couldn't find it in the online documentation... too bad. I'm wondering if I should delete my answer...

Comment: I think it's fine. I especially like "it's hard to come up with a specific simplification of a symbolic expression, especially if trigonometric functions are involved." There's no way to write a perfect function that can guess at what rearrangement is desired. The only way to solve the OP's request would be to write a bunch of custom code that probably would assume a lot about the format of the input.

Comment: @horchler thank you for the feedback. I moved the deprecated bit to the end to have the currently available `rewrite`-based attempt on top.

Comment: Unfortunately the output of `rewrite(fun,'sin')` in R2016a is not as nice: `(2*sin(T/2)^2 - 1)*(2*sin(fi/2)^2 - 1) - sin(T)*(2*sin(fi/2)^2 - 1) - sin(fi)*(2*sin(T/2)^2 - 1) - sin(T)*sin(fi)`. If you don't call `expand` first (third line of OP's code) then it's the same.

Comment: @Andras Deak, I'm affraid I wasn't able to obtain this particular form, but as horchler put it: it's tricky to explain Matlab what we really want to aquire.